# Is it possible to pass command-line arguments to @ARGV when using the -n or -p options?

Tags: perl, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments

I think the title of my question basically covers it. Here's a contrived example which tries to filter for input lines that exactly equal a parameterized string, basically a Perlish `fgrep -x`:

```
perl -ne 'chomp; print if $_ eq $ARGV[0];' bb <<<$'aa\nbb\ncc';
## Can't open bb: No such file or directory.
```

The problem of course is that the `-n` option creates an implicit `while (<>) { ... }` loop around the code, and the diamond operator gobbles up all command-line arguments for file names. So, although technically the `bb` argument *did* get to `@ARGV`, the whole program fails because the argument was *also* picked up by the diamond operator. The end result is, it is impossible to pass command-line arguments to the Perl program when using `-n`.

I suppose what I really want is an option that would create an implicit `while (<STDIN>) { ... }` loop around the code, so command-line arguments wouldn't be taken for file names, but such a thing does not exist.

I can think of three possible workarounds:

**1:** `BEGIN { ... }` block to copy and clear `@ARGV`.

```
perl -ne 'BEGIN { our @x = shift(@ARGV); } chomp; print if $_ eq $x[0];' bb <<<$'aa\nbb\ncc';
## bb
```

**2:** Manually code the while-loop in the one-liner.

```
perl -e 'while (<STDIN>) { chomp; print if $_ eq $ARGV[0]; }' bb <<<$'aa\nbb\ncc';
## bb
```

**3:** Find another way to pass the arguments, such as environment variables.

```
PAT=bb perl -ne 'chomp; print if $_ eq $ENV{PAT};' <<<$'aa\nbb\ncc';
## bb
```

The `BEGIN { ... }` block solution is undesirable since it constitutes a bit of a jarring context switch in the one-liner, is somewhat verbose, and requires messing with the special variable `@ARGV`.

I consider the manual while-loop solution to be more of a non-solution, since it forsakes the `-n` option entirely, and the point is I want to be able to use the `-n` option with command-line arguments.

The same can be said for the environment variable solution; the point is I want to be able to use command-line arguments with the `-n` option.

Is there a better way?

Comment: See also [Using -e and -s switch in perl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21496063/using-e-and-s-switch-in-perl)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've basically identified them all. The only one you missed, that I know of at least, is the option of passing switch arguments (instead of positional arguments):

```
$ perl -sne'chomp; print if $_ eq $kwarg' -- -kwarg=bb <<<$'aa\nbb\ncc';
bb
```

You could also use one of the many getopt modules instead of `-s`. This is essentially doing the same thing as manipulating `@ARGV` in a `BEGIN {}` block before the main program loop, but doing it for you and making it a little cleaner for a one-liner.

Comment: Very nice remembering the often forgotten `-s`.  I find it a bit less convenient than [awk's `-v` option](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html) (and normally for my usage perl is a better awk than awk).